# Cant connect to MySQL-DB : Unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, sql

I am making a small server with my friend, where you can log in and we want just us to see one tab.

When I tried my code on phptester.net it said:

> FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected 'is' (T_STRING) on line number 9

I have no clue, how to solve it.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $msg = '';

    $con = new mysqli('server', 'username', 'pwd', 'db');

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $name = $con->real_escape_string($name);
    $cmd = ' SELECT ID FROM user WHERE user = '$name'';
    $result = $con->query($cmd);

    $rowNumber = $result->num_rows;
    if($rowNumber != 0) {

        $msg = 'some text';

    }

        if($msgn != '') {

            echo '<a id=someid href="somelink">some text</a>';;

        }

    ?>
```

The only error I got was the one I showed you before.

Comment: When echoing strings, you need to but the string in quotes. This is PHP 101.

Comment: Can you show us where line 9 in that file is?

Comment: It is at $result = ...

Comment: @Kilian change the query to `"SELECT ID FROM user WHERE user = '$name'";`

Comment: But that line (or any of the posted code) doesn't contain any `is`, which the error message mentions.

Comment: I know, but it was added by PHPTESTER.net

Comment: Can you please copy/paste your actual code? Because in the posted code, line 9 is: `$name = $con->real_escape_string($name);` while you're saying that it's another line.

Comment: `' SELECT ID FROM user WHERE user = '$name'';`. There's your issue. Look at your quotes. You should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually escaping the data and building your queries like that. It would also solve the current quoting issues.

Comment: But what does this mean: FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '$name' (T_VARIABLE) on line number ?

Comment: ` $cmd = ' SELECT ID FROM user WHERE user = '$name'';
` this is not correct...change this to   `$cmd = " SELECT ID FROM user WHERE user = '$name'";`

Comment: Now it says: FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected 'is' (T_STRING) on line number 9 again

Comment: I would **strongly** recommend that you read the manual about strings, concatenation and variable interpolation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php That's PHP 101.

Answer (score 0):

You have not echoed the message properly. Change

```
echo <a id=someid href="somelink">some text</a>;
```

to

```
 echo '<a id=someid href="somelink">some text</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks, but there's still the problem with the connection

Comment: update the question accordingly please @Kilian